# Java 8 method references : validation of methods at compile time

Tags: java, java-8

I'd like to use the new *method references* of Java 8 to provide more validation of some code at compile time.

Let's say I have a `validateMethod` method which requires one parameter : a "method" to be validated. For example :

```
validateMethod(foo, "methodA");
```

Here, the method would validate that `foo#methodA()` exists, *at runtime*.

Using method references, I'd like to be able to do :

```
validateMethod(foo::methodA);
```

So the existence of the method would be validated *at compile time*.

The problem is that it seems method references **have** to be assigned to a functional interface. For example, this :

```
Object dummy = foo::methodA;
```

Generates the error : "*The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*".

If I create a functional interface that has a compatible signature with the `methodA` method, it works :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunctionalInterface
{
    public String run();
}
MyFunctionalInterface dummy = foo::methodA;
```

Now the existence of `foo#methodA()` is validated at compile time, which is what I want!

But...

Let's say `validateMethod` doesn't know the signature of the method it has to validate. Is it still possible to implement it then?

Let's pretend we don't care about ambiguity and overloaded methods. Is it possible in Java 8 to implement some kind of method which would trigger the validation of *any* method reference?

For example :

```
public class Foo
{
    public String methodA()
    {
        return "methodA";
    }

    public String methodB(String str)
    {
        return "methodB";
    }

    public String methodC(String str, int nbr)
    {
        return "methodC";
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
validateMethod(foo::methodA); // Compile
validateMethod(foo::methodB); // Compile
validateMethod(foo::methodC); // Compile
validateMethod(foo::methodD); // Error!
```

Would it be possible to implement `validateMethod` in such a way that any method reference would be accepted, so the existence of the method would be validated at compile time?

I tried :

```
public void validateMethod(Object obj){}
```

But it doesn't work : "*The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*"

This would work :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunctionalInterface
{
    public String run();
}
public void validateMethod(MyFunctionalInterface param){}
```

But only for `methodA` of the `Foo` class, because its signature (no parameter) is compatible with the functional interface's method signature!

Would it be possible to implement the functional interface `MyFunctionalInterface` in such a way that *any* method reference would be a valid parameter and therefore would be validated at compile time?

Any other ways you see to validate the existence of a method at compile time?

Comment: You reason as if method's name has somehow more importance that its signature. To the best of my knowledge, in Java both are equally important. Knowing method name without its signature is as useless as knowing the signature without a name.

Comment: @9000 I agree, but my real use case is more complicated then this simplified example. I'm builing a framework which would be responsible to inject the appropriate parameters in the "validated methods" when calling them. The parameter types would still have to be validated I agree, but the more important point for the users is to specify the methods to be called. A compile time validation would help, even if it would not solve everything.

Comment: While I understand your concerns, I still suppose that "to specify the methods to be called" _means_ to specify method name _and_ signature. Else unresolvable ambiguities ensue. I can imagine that you could force a build-time check by writing an annotation and including an annotation processor into the build chain. Inside them you could use normal 'runtime' reflection and select appropriate methods by name first.

Comment: I try to be as type safe as possible, but of course there are problems, mainly with overloading. But I could forbid the use of overloading (runtime check). Your annotation processor is interesting but I feel it's a little bit too complex, and I do not have experience with it. The best, of course, would be to be able to specify a method reference with its full signature like so : `foo::methodC(String,int)`.

Comment: What does it mean to "validateMethod" in your context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use **method references**, which are really the *short-hands for lambda expressions*, as **method literals**, which are the *syntactic references to methods* (much like Foo.class is the syntactic reference to class instance of Foo). These two are not the same, and this is the reason for the impedance you encounter. Things you try are the abuse of language feature which javac compiler utterly resists.

Unfortunately, there is no method literals in Java, so you will have to describe the method by other means, e.g. Reflection, MethodHandles.Lookup, etc. I think it is very easy to come up with the reflective checker for this kind of thing, or even build up the annotation processor to check the existence of given methods in compile time.

Comment: *"which are really the short-hands for lambda expressions"* ... They are different internally and does always behave the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like the following:

```
public class Validate {
    public String methodA() { return "methodA"; }
    public String methodB(String s) { return "methodB"; }
    public String methodC(String s, int n) { return "methodC"; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Validate foo = new Validate();
        validateMethod(foo::methodA);
        validateMethod(foo::methodB);
        validateMethod(foo::methodC);
    }

    private interface Func0 { void method(); }
    private interface Func1<T> { void method(T t); }
    private interface Func2<T, U> { void method(T t, U u); }
    private interface Func3<T, U, V> { void method(T t, U u, V v); }

    public static void validateMethod(Func0 f) { }
    public static <T> void validateMethod(Func1<T> f) { }
    public static <T, U> void validateMethod(Func2<T, U> f) { }
    public static <T, U, V> void validateMethod(Func3<T, U, V> f) { }
}
```

But you'll need to provide an interface and an overload of `validateMethod` for every arity of method you need to validate. Also, it will not work if the method to validate is overloaded, unless you add an explicit cast:

```
    // if there are two methodA's:
    public String methodA() { return "methodA"; }
    public String methodA(long x) { return "methodA"; }

        validateMethod(foo::methodA); // this doesn't work
        validateMethod((Func0)foo::methodA); // this does
        validateMethod((Func1<Long>)foo::methodA); // so does this
```

Answer (score -1):

would `interface Method { public Object runMethod(Object... args); }` work? the only potential problem i see is methods that deal with primitive types, but perhaps they could be upcast automatically to `Double`'s / `Long`'s, dont really have a running java8 compiler atm.

Comment: Creative thinking,  but it doesn't seem to work. The signature is interpreted as Object[].

Comment: Even a simpler case,  such as using BiFunction to accept any reference to a 2-in-1-out method,  doesn't work well. As soon as there is ambiguity among overloads,  you have to write a cast with the correct type parameters.